# Android "Heisenbug" only on real hardware

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a weird bug in Android. My program consists only of a list fragment/view with a recycler, adapter and view holder and a second fragment/view with google maps API. when I switch those activities for long enough, the app freezes. When I restart the app (kill the process and open it again) it starts frozen again, until I completely uninstall it and build it again.

Now the weird part is, it only happens when I build on real hardware, not the Android Studio emulator.

I assume some cache is getting full until an overflow and it doesnt get emptied at a new start. and on an emulator the cache simply has too much room to overflow? What would be my approach in finding out what causes this? How do I monitor what activity/method causes lots of writes without deletion or consumes other resouces at runtime?

Comment: Have you checked the output of any logs? i.e. LogCat

Comment: OK now it gets weirder, now I can't even reproduce the bug on my personal phone, it was only on two other phones we used at college and I did not change anything in the code in the meantime

Comment: But when we are back at college, would this here be the best approach of dealing with it: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html ???

Comment: The Memory Monitor may be helpful, but might be overkill for your problem. You mention that this occurs when you 'switch the activites' for long enough. Is it possible you are creating new instances of the Activities in addition to the previous ones when you switch and that is eventually causing memory issues? Try using `finish()` when starting new Activities?

Comment: Oh wait, I got somethig wrong, both views are in the same activity, but different fragments. They are being destroyed and recreated by the fragment manager. I will correct that in my original post.